# error in MainActivity.jave file

Tags: android, android-layout

i am editing mainactivity.java code file this error occur 
**R cannot be resolved to a variable**
when i import R then their further more new error occurs like 
**bAdd cannot be resolved or is not a field
bSub cannot be resolved or is not a field
tvDisplay cannot be resolved or is not a field**
kindly guide me how can i remove these errors

Comment: Are you using Eclipse? If so, try and "Clean and Build" your project. That might resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

**Project -> Clean** : do it a few times until you see the errors go away.

Select **"Build Automatically"** so that every time you clean the project, it will be rebuilt. And yeah, make sure you are saving the file before cleaning it (I know it is weird but sometimes the errors refuse to go away until you save it and then Clean it). Make sure that there is no error in the files in the **layout** folder, as it sometimes prevents the auto-generation of the code in R.java

Also, make sure that your code in MainActivity.java **does not** have **`import android.R`**. Eclipse tends to add that when you are managing the imports.

Answer (score 0):

R is a generated source that recreated while building the project. Make sure that the project is built (in eclipse, there is an option for auto build in project->build automaticcaly).
Do not import R. This is not the R you looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The error causes due to your any of **XML** file contains error.So check all xml files and clean the project and build it.